How to install CA certificate into LocaMachine Root via powershell under standard user (Administrators group)
I need to install CA certificate into LocaMachine Root via powershell. I'm trying to run this script with elevated privileges to Standard user from Administrators group.
Import-PfxCertificate -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'certificatePassword' -AsPlainText -Force) -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root -FilePath 'filePath'

But, it fails on Acces Denied error.
If I execute the same script with elevated privileges to predefined windows Administrator user, then it works without error.
How to configure Standard user permissions to allow access?
I need to install it remotely via API and I don't want to require the predefined windows Administrator credentials from app using this API.
Thx in advance.
UPDATE (here is the screenshot of Standard user from Administrators group and the C# code where the process is started with credentials of this user):

command = the powershell script above
adminUsername = 'Admin'
adminPasswprd = '*****'
domain = 'computername'
public static (bool, string) ExecuteCommand(string command, string adminUsername, string adminPassword, string domain = "")
    {
        try
        {
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in adminPassword)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            // Create PowerShell process information
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command \"{command}\"",
                UseShellExecute = false, 
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UserName = adminUsername,
                Password = securePassword,
                Domain = domain,
                Verb = "runas" 
            };

            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo = processInfo;
                process.Start();
                string standardOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                string errorOutput = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                process.WaitForExit();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorOutput))
                {
                    standardOutput += Environment.NewLine + "Error: " + errorOutput;
                }

                return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorOutput), standardOutput);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (false, $"Error during PowerShell script execution: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }


What exactly do you mean by "elevated privileges to Standard user from Administrators group"? Can you detail the steps you've taken to create and configure the user account with which you're getting Access Denied?

Hi Mathias, I updated post with more details.
